# android application label and activity label

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I found out that if I defined the `label` attribute for my `MainActivity` and `application` in the `manifest.xml`. Then only the `label` value of the `MainActivity` will show on the action bar. So I wonder what does the `label` of `application` for the `android` app.

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [devloper.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) documentation.

> A user-readable label for the application as a whole, and a default label for each of the application's components. See the individual label attributes for activity, activity-alias, service, receiver, and provider elements.
>
> The label should be set as a reference to a string resource, so that it can be localized like other strings in the user interface. However, as a convenience while you're developing the application, it can also be set as a raw string.

I guess the part you are interested in is

> A user-readable label for the application as a whole, and a default label for each of the application's components.

Comment: so what that means is if I do not define labels for activities then the application label will be the default label for each of the activities?

Answer (score 3):

With [PackageManager.getActivityInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getActivityInfo%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getActivityInfo%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29) returns the information about a particular activity class.

ActivityInfo contain fields `labelRes` and `name`, `labelRes` is what you defined in the label attribute of your MainActivity.

**How to get the label of your activity?**

```
 ApplicationInfo appInfo = this.getApplicationInfo();
            String appName = (String) this.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
```